# OpenEvent, getlasterror returns 2

Tags: windows, driver

I'm building a windows UMDF 2.0 driver and when I call OpenEvent I get an error of 2.  any help would be great.  below is my code

```
HANDLE userEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, myUserEvent);
```

std::cout<

Comment: for me similarly.. OpenEventW returns not NULL, but GetLastError() gives "2"
When this could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7,8 require security descriptors while wec does not. Their default security descriptors are different.

Also if your events are to be accessed by different users or by elevated processes you need to make it a global event, otherwise it will not be able to access it.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out, when you create a driver user event it has a default security permissions as high, so you have to create a security descriptor and pass it in to override the the default.  For some reason it gives spits out an error 2 which is cant find file.  hope this helps someone in the future.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx